# Trigger AFTER update syntax error

Tags: mysql

Im trying to build a simple trigger after update that will update another table, but I can't find the syntax error here. To do this I'm usign the phpMyAdmin wizard.

The error:

> MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'UPDATE question SET question.fname_author = new.fname,
>   question.lname_au' at line 4

---

```
TABLES STRUCTURE:

  question             user_question         users

 - id PK               -id_user PFK         -id  PK
 - fname_author        -id_question PFK     -fname
 - lname_author        -fname_author FK     -lname 
 - question            -lname_author FK     -email  
 - category            -question FK         -office
 - level               -office FK           -password
 - created_at          -created_at          -created_at 
 - updated_at          -updated_at          -updated_at
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TAU_users_UPDATE_dati_domanda` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
            SET @id_question = (SELECT user_question.id_question
                               FROM user_question
                               WHERE user_question.id_user =new.id);
            UPDATE question
            SET
                fname_author = new.fname,
                lname_author = new.lname
        WHERE question.id = @id_question
END;
```

Comment: try a semi-colon after your initial query, ie where you set @id_question...

Comment: Already tried but nothing

Comment: can share your table structure

Comment: Dont worry about my tables structure, that was my fault while typing on the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provide by @Renzo should work...

I was working on testing the o/p code here with some test data ... as usual too late...

Whatever, I will post it anyway as it works...

So I created an [SQLFddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e81b/1) with some test data.

Trigger Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TAU_users_UPDATE_dati_domanda` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
            SET @id_question = (SELECT user_question.id_question
                               FROM user_question
                               WHERE user_question.id_user =new.id);

            UPDATE question
            SET
                question.fname_author = new.fname,
                question.lname_author = new.lname
        WHERE question.id = @id_question;
END;//
```

Not important - note: qualified column names in the `update`.

*Test data before*:

Users:

```
id  fname             lname             email           office      password Created_at
1   fname_u1          lname_u1          u1@here.com     office_u1   pwd_u1   September, 17 2015 11:57:11
2   fname_u2          lname_u2          u2@here.com     office_u2   pwd_u2   September, 17 2015 11:57:12
```

Question:

```
id  fname_author      lname_author      question           category level created_at
1   fname_q1          lname_q1          what question q1?  cat_1    1     September, 17 2015 11:57:12
2   fname_u2          lname_u2          what question q2?  cat_2    2     September, 17 2015 11:57:12
```

Update Statement:

```
UPDATE  users 
SET users.fname = 'fname_u2_new_fn01',
    users.lname = 'lname_u2_new_fn01'
WHERE users.id = 2//
```

*Test Data After Update*:

Users:

```
id  fname             lname             email           office      password Created_at
1   fname_u1          lname_u1          u1@here.com     office_u1   pwd_u1   September, 17 2015 11:57:11
2   fname_u2_new_fn01 lname_u2_new_fn01 u2@here.com     office_u2   pwd_u2   September, 17 2015 11:57:12
```

Question:

```
id  fname_author      lname_author      question           category level created_at
1   fname_q1          lname_q1          what question q1?  cat_1    1     September, 17 2015 11:57:12
2   fname_u2_new_fn01 lname_u2_new_fn01 what question q2?  cat_2    2     September, 17 2015 11:57:12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TAU_users_UPDATE_dati_domanda` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
            SET @id_question = (SELECT user_question.id_question
                               FROM user_question
                               WHERE user_question.id_user =new.id)
            UPDATE question
            SET
                question.fname_author = new.fname,
                question.lname_author = new.lname


        WHERE question.id = @id_question
END;
```

in:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `TAU_users_UPDATE_dati_domanda` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
            SET @id_question = (SELECT user_question.id_question
                               FROM user_question
                               WHERE user_question.id_user =new.id);
            UPDATE question
            SET
                fname_author = new.fname,
                lname_author = new.lname
        WHERE question.id = @id_question;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

For the syntax and example of triggers, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html and the relevant comment about the use of `BEGIN ... END` inside triggers.

Comment: Done, but nothing, the mySQL error message always say that the error is at line 5 where UPDATE begin.
If I run just the initial query or the update mySQL doesn't find any error

Comment: On which table is the trigger? Could you edit your question to show it?

Comment: I modified the answer with a link to an example of the MySQL syntax for triggers.